# php dynamic array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know is there such thing as dynamic array_intersect? Anyway i have 3 arrays ( later there will be much more arrays)

```
$kaID = array();
$tgID = array();
$ciID = array();
```

I want to find matching values for all arrays using array_intersect
Arrays can be created and filled with values or not.
It can be only one populated array OR there can be all three. (later on there will be much more arrays.

How to iterate and create some kind of dynamic expression and get something like this:
`array_intersect ($kaID, $tgID,$ciID,.... );`

Comment: Can you be more specific? `array_intersect(...)` already take as much array as you want.

Comment: if you are using php 7 you can also do `array_intersect($kaID,...[$tgID,$ciID])`

Comment: Arrays can be created or not. I dont know final number of arrays

Comment: Is your question about how to create an array (of arrays) from a list of variables that are each an array, using PHP? i.e. how to convert separate variables `$kgID, $tgID ...`  into an array: `array( $kgID, $tgID, ... )`

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
$collection = [];

//Dynamic
foreach($ids as $id) {
   $collection[] = $id;
}

$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $collection);
```