# Getting value of nested array's which exist in every array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested, array-intersect

I have the following (nested) array:

```
array(3) { [16]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(159) [1]=> int(160) [2]=> int(158) } 
           [21]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(160) [1]=> int(158) } 
           [19]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(158) [1]=> int(159) } }
```

As you can see it contains 3 child array's. The child array's all contain the integer '158' as an value but also '159'. I want to somehow loop trough the child array's and do a check if all child array's contain that value. Then I want to return an array with only these values.

I know i could use array_intersect for this however the nested array's are generated dynamically so i'm not sure how to deal with this using array intersect:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('158','250','342'); 
$arr2 = array('158','142','352');

$diff1 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
print_r( $diff1 );
//RETURNS Array ( [0] => 158 )
?>
```

Comment: You want to get common values in all arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the splat operator([`...`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)) to pass all the subarrays into `array_intersect()` in one go...

```
$arr1 = [['158','250','342'],['158','142','352'],['1421','158','3521']];

$diff1 = array_intersect(...$arr1);
print_r( $diff1 );
//RETURNS Array ( [0] => 158 )
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do it these days.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit searching around I found the following:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $productStoreArray);
```

As seen on: [php dynamic array_intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398040/php-dynamic-array-intersect)

This solves my problem because it returns to me:

```
//RETURNS Array ( [0] => 158, 1 => 159 )
```